# Daily login Reward using Google Analytics

Tags: authentication, google-analytics, google-analytics-4, reward

we would like to look at implementing a daily Login reward

this could be if you log in 7 days consecutively or 3 days consecutively

we currently do not count the days that you login to our software

We do track successful logins in both GA4 and GA3

Doe Google Analytics have a segment or custom code one could use to be able to track individuals login "streaks" that we could use to trigger a visual to show this?

I have searched the web and do not seem to find how to write custom code and I am hoping this community could assist